# Tastypie - Create Operation with CSV imports

Tags: python, django, csv, tastypie

I am using Django Tastypie for the REST API - Services. So far its great and simple and i was able to meet all the simple CRUD requirements.

But now I have situation of CSV imports. Need to import let's say 50+ users from CSV to the User Auth DB Table of Django. I am using http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html for API reference.

Does anyone know how to perform a csv import for django user auth module and create users using tastypie api using file uploads ?? I am not even sure whether this API module can handle file-uploads like this. ( Sorry of the beginner question )

If not .. is there a work around or some sort of a tweak for the above mentioned scenario.

Kindly guide me in the right direction. If you know some kind of kick-starter guide, let me know.

**Update:**

```
def dispatch(self, request_type, request, **kwargs):
        self.body = request.body
        return super(TestResource, self).dispatch(request_type, request, **kwargs)

def post_list(self, request, **kwargs):
    deserialized = self.deserialize(request, self.body, format=request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json'))
    deserialized = self.alter_deserialized_detail_data(request, deserialized)
    bundle = self.build_bundle(data=dict_strip_unicode_keys(deserialized), request=request)
    updated_bundle = self.obj_create(bundle, **self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))
    location = self.get_resource_uri(updated_bundle)

    if not self._meta.always_return_data:
        return http.HttpCreated(location=location)
    else:
        updated_bundle = self.full_dehydrate(updated_bundle)
        updated_bundle = self.alter_detail_data_to_serialize(request, updated_bundle)
        return self.create_response(request, updated_bundle, response_class=http.HttpCreated, location=location)

def deserialize(self, request, data, format=None):
    if not format:
        format = request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json')

    if format == 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded':
        return request.POST

    if format.startswith('multipart'):
        data = request.POST.copy()
        data.update(request.FILES)
        return data
    return super(TestResource, self).deserialize(request, data, format)
```

Comment: I have updated the question on your request. Please take a look at the update section. I have tried to use deserialize method to handle the multipart data. If format is specified then I choose application type as the given format else I choose Json format. The problem is that the user doesnt get added to the userauth table .. and I am not getting any errors in the console. P.S I am newbie so let me know if there are some other ways to troubleshoot and give you more info on the same. 


Thanks in advance.